# splitting a http response by \r\n\r\n using strtok

Tags: c, string, http, httpresponse

I am attempting to split this string:

```
#define INVALID_NUMBER_PARAMS "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\ncontent-type: text/html\r\ncontent-encoding: identity\r\ncontent-length: 59\r\n\r\nCould not fulfill request due to wrong number of paramaters"
```

at the delim: \r\n\r\n using this function:

```
void splitString(struct Arr* arr, char* str, char* delim) {

    if (!initialAlloc(arr)) {

        exit(1);

    }

    char* subStr = strtok(str, delim);


    while (subStr != NULL) {

        addToArr(arr, subStr);
        
        subStr = strtok(NULL, delim);

    }

}
```

However, using it where char* str is the response and delim= \r\n\r\n results in the response being split at each header end instead of where the body starts. I have tried to double backslash the delim as well and even tried multiple variations of it like \r\r \n\n \r\n\r\n but I still get random splits. Using \r\r results in this:

```
str: http/1.1 400 bad 
str: equest
content-type: text/html
content-encoding: identity
content-length: 59

could not fulfill 
str: equest due to w
str: ong numbe
str:  of pa
str: amate
str: s
```

I am calling the function like this to recieve the output:

```
splitString(&split, tempStr, "\\r\\r");
                for (int x = 0; x < split.currentSize; x++) {
                    printf("str: %s\n", split.cArr[x]);
                }
```

How can I make this function split at \r\n\r\n to get 2 indexes, one that has all of the headers, and one that contains the body?

Comment: Why not just `strstr()`?

Comment: Instead of guessing randomly what's in your data, why not *look*? Dump it out as hex.

Comment: If you pass `"\r\n"` as the delimiter to `strtok` it will match ether of the characters, it isn't looking for a sequence.

Comment: @tadman i already had strtok for splitString as you can see and I dont see why it would not work

Comment: @RetiredNinja so effectively, \r\n\r\n is the same as \r\n?

Comment: You need to examine your data more closely. The standard specifies CRLFCRLF but you may find your data is LFLF, but servers will send the former.

Comment: @tadman wouldn't say im guessing as I am the one sending the response to myself

Comment: What is the line encoding of your response?

Comment: @user18043747 Yes. As suggested `strstr` searches for a substring match.

Comment: @tadman I am sending it as plain text over http/1.1 with no encoding

Comment: Again, what is the **line encoding** of your response? "Plain text" is not a line encoding. It's usually CR, LF, or CRLF.

Comment: @tadman, How am i sending LFLF, should I backslash the responses?

Comment: I'd suggest storing them in sample files and *confirming* the file encoding with a tool like `file`, `hexdump`, etc. If you're expressing the examples as code, please show the code as an edit to your question, e.g. as a C string.

Comment: @user18043747, yes, `\r\n\r\n` is equivalent to `\r\n` as a `strtok` delimiter string, but I don't think you've fully understood.  That string is not significant as a *sequence* of characters, but rather as several *individual* characters.  `strtok` will split at any run of one or more of any of them.

Comment: strtok() also mutates input which is not what I usually want (opposed to `strpbrk()`).  As you are dealing with network buffers prefer `memmem()` to `strstr()` if available, or write a parser to iterate through the header one "\r\n" separated chunk at a time.

Comment: Instead of splitting the string consider returning an array of (char *, size_t).  You still the char * but with size_t you can leave the original string intact and a bunch of operations are faster if you have the string length upfront.

Comment: Why not just split at `'\n'` and ignore any `'\r'`? Yes, it is not the question but it would make parsing more tolerant and easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to use strstr as suggested to find the correct index of the substring then placed everything to the right of \r\n\r\n in a tempString then strlened it